# Cloud Foundry over Google Cloud. Missing API target endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-foundry

I've succesfully deployed "Cloud Foundry" on "Google Cloud".

Now I've installed the "Cloud Foundry CLI" on my laptop and I want to manage my instance of "Cloud Foundry" on "Google Cloud".

I've launched the following command

```
cf login -a
```

but this command requires also the IP address of a target API endpoint.

I don't understand how to get the IP address I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API endpoint is the IP of a load balancer, or a DNS name that resolves to the load balancer. CF comes with an HAProxy that can serve this purpose for development environments (it is not horizontally scalable).

To get started quickly, identify the public IP of the HAProxy VM in your deployment.

e.g.
cf login -a http://10.100.0.34 -u admin